# "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." but message was received

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension. I try to send message from background.js (service worker) to content.js (content script), I was faced with the above mentioned error in my background.js console but message was received at content.js console. Explain how  to fix the error and how I was able to send the message.

Background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender , sendMessage)=>{
    if(message.action == "changeTabColor"){
        chrome.tabs.query({},(tabs)=>{
            console.log(tabs);
            tabs.forEach((tab) => {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "changeTabColor"});
            });
        })
    }
})

console.log(
    "background script"
)
```

Content.js

```
console.log("content script  working fine ");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendMessage) => {
    if (message.action == "changeTabColor") {
        console.log("button pressed ");
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue'; 
    }})
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "club-tab",
  "description": "to club active tabs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
  "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you need to [re-inject content scripts](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. However, some tabs like `chrome://` (including the newtab) or `chrome-extension://` can't run content scripts, so sendMessage will show the error anyway. You can suppress it like this:

```js
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {action: "changeTabColor"}).catch(() => {});
```